# svg currentScale property doesn't change on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am currently embedding svgs inside a object tag for my website. The zoom and pan works fine with mouse scroll on IE browser but on Google Chrome the currentScale property doesn't change on zoom or pan. Its always '1'. Please find my code below,

### HTML

`<object class="svgclass" data="img/svgfile.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
Your browser doesn't support SVG
</object>`

### Javasript

I cannot put the entire code but the below line has the issue,

```
svgroot.currentScale = newscale;
```

Whatever might be the value for newscale, the svgroot.currentScale is always 1. It works perfectly fine on IE browser (ver 9, 10, 11) but not on Chrome (ver 35). I simply cannot find why the property cannot be updated. I have spend too much time on this. Any help will be really useful.

Thank you

Comment: This is reported as http://crbug.com/174568.